# Get All WP Posts older than 15 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to filter the WP_Query to retrive all woocommerce order `(post_type = shop_order)` with particular status that are older than 15 minutes.

I.e. All posts that have been last modified on or before (now - 15 minutes ) // Hope I'm clear.

Below What I've tried

```
 function filter_where($where = '') {
            //posts in the last 15 minutes
           $where .= " AND post_modified > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('INTERVAL 15 MINUTE')) . "'";
            return $where;
        }
        add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');

 $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array('completed')
                )
            )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    $order_id = $loop->post->ID;


    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
print_r("<pre>");
        print_r($order);
      print_r("</pre>");
 endwhile;
```

However that returns all record, Seems like have to modify the $where query, how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Can you show us where you are declaring `$loop`?

Comment: have updated, just above the while loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you need to filter the `posts_where`? Can't you just use [date query parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)? In your case, specifically `before`.

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'before'    => '15 minutes ago'
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I can't test this right now, so can't verify if it would work. If you are modifying an archive then you should definitely adjust the query via [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) in lieu of creating new query.

Answer (score 2):

try this change date('Y-m-d', strtotime('INTERVAL 15 MINUTE')) to date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 minutes'))

```
function filter_where($where = ''){
            //posts in the last 15 minutes
   $where .= " AND post_modified > '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 minutes')) . "'";
   return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```